# Adding up variables gives strange outcome value

Tags: eclipse, if-statement

I am using an if statement looking like the following:

```
if(x=x){
a = a + b;
}
```

The variable "b" is in my case influenced by several other factors.
An outcome for example could be:
a=5+6. The outcome would be 11. However, in my case the outcome turns out way higher and is different everytime the if-statement runs. When I use an integer instead of the variable "b" it does work and will give me the right outcome.

I hope I made myself clear and someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear at all.  Please take some time to read [ask], and post a [mcve].

Comment: Just a note: if you're forced to explain what each variable represents, it clearly means that the variable name is a bad name. Use `redTeamIncome` as a variable name for the red team income. Not `tri`, which means nothing.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have reformed my questions and used an example to make myself more clear. It's hard to explain though.

Comment: @JB Nizet Reading your comment I thought of this myself. This will be my first next thing on my to-do list. Thanks!

Comment: Nope.  Still not clear.  Please tag with the language.  Is this java, C, C++?  If it is "hard" to explain, Again, please read [ask], and provide a [mcve].  If you can't do that, then don't expect much results here.

Comment: Eclipse is just your development environment and is used to program many different programming languages. You must tell us which language you are asking about.

Comment: `if (x=x)` not very useful in Java... how you know the value of `b` at the time the addition is being executed? Are Threads involved?  Addition does work, if no overflow happening

Answer (score 0):

I have read all of your comments. I have taken all advice and changed my project here and there. It turned out there was a loop in editing the variable. Instead of adding up once it added up infinitely.